# Grouping by one column and counting from multiple columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query on the below scenario

Result

Example:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB    
A           B         
B           C
```

Result:

```
ColumnA   countB   countC
A         1         0
B         0         1
```

Comment: The title says what you need to do, GROUP BY one column, and COUNT() the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample data, no aggregation is needed:

```
SELECT columnA,
       (CASE WHEN columnB = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countB,
       (CASE WHEN columnB = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countC
FROM t;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
  Select 
       columnA,
       count(ColumnB) as ColumnB,
       count(ColumnC) as ColumnC
    From Table
    Group By
       columnA
```

Comment: sorry for the incorrect question. Please check the edited one

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough sample data to confirm that, but based also on the title of your question you seem to be looking for condition aggregation :

```
SELECT
    columnA,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN columnB = 'B' THEN 1 END) countB,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN columnB = 'C' THEN 1 END) countC
FROM mytable
GROUP BY columnA
```

Comment: Remember that `COUNT(column)` counts non-null values only.

Comment: @jarlh : right. I simplified the query accordingly, thanks !

Comment: sorry for the incorrect question. please see the updated one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your real scenario is larger that that, I think that is better to use a pivot

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(ColumnA CHAR(1), ColumnB CHAR(1))

INSERT @table VALUES ('A', 'B')
INSERT @table VALUES ('B', 'C')

SELECT ColumnA, A AS CountA, B AS CountB, C AS CountC, D AS CountD....
FROM
(
    SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
    FROM @table
) AS Source
PIVOT
(
    Count(ColumnB)
    FOR ColumnB IN ([A], [B], [C], [D].....)
) AS Pvt
```